# Why I'm getting this type of error while installing a npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-package

```
added 1 package, and audited 1466 packages in 16s

206 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: Did you run `npm audit`?

Answer (score 5):

What you're getting is not an error. When you run `npm install` or `npm update` in the command prompt and when it is done they recommend you to run a new command called `npm fund`.

**When you run `npm fund` it will list all the modules and packages you have installed that were created by companies or organizations that need money (donations) for their projects.** You will get a list of pages where you can send donations to support their projects.

They basically give you a list of all the projects that needs contributions or donations for their projects. You can go to those webpages and donate money to those projects.

**For the high severity vulnerabilities problem, it is only a new npm functionality to warn users about vulnerabilities in the packages they're installing. It's only showing warning about vulnerabilities in the packages you're installing.**

**npm audit command does is just running a full fledged `npm install` command.** You can read more about that in npm [audit command page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit/)

Hope this helped!